# Angular + JavaScript: Dynamic loading using direct JS instead of Path

Tags: javascript, angular, es6-modules

I have some code in Angular 13+ where I am loading a Dynamic component. It works well, however, I am looking to load the component directly using the JS of the component instead of using the path where the JS file is located. How can I make this work?

HTML (working code)

```
  <div>
    <button (click)="loadModule()">Load Module</button>
  </div>  
  <ng-template #container></ng-template>
```

TS (working code)

```
  @ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef })
  container!: ViewContainerRef;

  async loadModule() {
    const {DynamicComponent} = await import("../app/dynamic/dynamic.component");
    const moduleRef = createNgModuleRef(DynamicModule, this.injector);
    this.container.clear();
    this.componentRef = this.container.createComponent(DynamicComponent);
  }
```

And I would like to do something like:

TS (non-working code)

```
  @ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef })
  container!: ViewContainerRef;

  async loadModule() {
    // Using JavaScript code directly instead of going back to the Server to load the code
    const {DynamicComponent} = await import("\"use strict\";(self.webpackChunkangular_15_test_1=self.webpackChunkangular_15_test_1||[]).push([[989],{989:(s,c,a)=>{a.r(c),a.d(c,{DynamicComponent:()=>o});var t=a(845);let o=(()=>{class n{ngOnInit(){}}return n.\u0275fac=function(e){return new(e||n)},n.\u0275cmp=t.Xpm({type:n,selectors:[[\"app-dynamic\"]],decls:2,vars:0,template:function(e,p){1&e&&(t.TgZ(0,\"p\"),t._uU(1,\"my dynamic text works!\"),t.qZA())},encapsulation:2}),n})()}}]);");
    const moduleRef = createNgModuleRef(DynamicModule, this.injector);
    this.container.clear();
    this.componentRef = this.container.createComponent(DynamicComponent);
  }
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: My guess is this will never work (import needs a file). But the real question is, why would you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: @MikeOne It is a feature requirement, the very same JS code to be imported is also dynamic, so it can't just be loaded from a static file.